# why auto dupplicate value in my array

Tags: php, arrays

I tried to create a shopping basket in my project, but some problem to handle this.
My project basket must allow duplicate value, but my code auto duplicate last insert to array. Why does this happen, and how to solve this auto duplicate?

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['basket'])){

    $point = count($_SESSION['basket']);
    echo " point = ".$point;
    $value = end((array_keys($_SESSION['basket'])));
    $value++;
}else{
    $value = 0;
    echo " point = 0";
}

    if(isset($_GET['id'] , $_GET['meter'] , $_GET['color'])){
        $id = $_GET['id'];  

        $color = $_GET['color'];    

        $meter = $_GET['meter'];    

        $selected_product = array($id , $color , $meter);

        list($_SESSION['basket'][$value][0],$_SESSION['basket'][$value][1] , $_SESSION['basket'][$value][2]) = $selected_product;
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($_SESSION['basket']);
        echo "</pre>";


    }


?>
```

Comment: When do you start your session? You're also using `array()` instead of `list()`. `array($foo, $bar) = $array` is invalid code. `list($foo, bar) = $array` is not.

Comment: `array(...) = $value` makes no sense... That's a flat-out parse error and this script could never have worked as-is.

Comment: @h2ooooooo when posting code i change "list" to "array" and forget return to "list" , Excuse me
and session start in other place as code

Comment: this shopping product have any color and any meter and user can select any color for buy
for facility buying i want to enable variuos color as one product
for this work i make simple $key generator this multiple array (for To avoid re-writing to one key)
but when insert data in array and change $key value , prviose data and new data plased in array

Comment: for example:
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [2]=>
    string(4) "5544"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "green"
    [0]=>
    string(2) "11"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [2]=>
    string(4) "5544"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "green"
    [0]=>
    string(2) "11"
  }
  [2]=>
array(3) {
    [2]=>
    string(3) "234"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "black"
    [0]=>
    string(2) "10"
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though its not exactly clear from your question. To remove duplication in `array`  use [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/function.array-unique)

You also had a typo at

```
array($_SESSION['basket'][$value][0],$_SESSION['basket'][$value][1] , $_SESSION['basket'][$value][2]) = $selected_product;
```

Comment: yes , i change code and forget to return

list($_SESSION['basket'][$value][0],$_SESSION['basket'][$value][1] , $_SESSION['basket'][$value][2]) = $selected_product;